# how can I find policies hyperledger fabric on service without configtx?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to know polcies without `configtx.yaml` when hyperledger server is running. Because, I want to test how the permissions change as each layer of policy changes.

Is there any `peer command` for finding policies?

Comment: just commenting cause I am looking for the same answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `peer channel fetch config` command. Something similar to:

```
peer channel fetch config myconfig.pb -o <my-orderer-and-port> -c <my-channel-name> --tls --cafile ordercafile.tls
```

This will return you a Protobuf file (myconfig.pb) and you can decode this into json using the `configxlator` command (you may need to download this binary as part of the fabric binaries).  For example:

```
configtxlator proto_decode --input myconfig.pb --type common.Block --output ./myconfig.json
```

This will be a long JSON file but you might be able to use `diff` between versions and see if your changes have been applied.